# Python - proxy that listens for only one URL

Tags: python-2.7, proxy, mitmproxy

I am trying to make a proxy in Python that listens to a specific port and is set up on my computer ip (basically like burp suite, or Charles)
I need this proxy to 'watch' for one specific URL which I know and I need it to automatically change the parameters and then pass the URL with the changed parameters

EXAMPLE:

Before:
www.google.com?debug=false

After:
www.google.com?debug=true

I was thinking of using the MITM proxy module.
I think the URL will be HTTPS so I will need to generate a certificate correct?

Any help or insight will be valuable!

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Mitmproxy can intercept SSL/TLS, but you need to install the mitmproxy CA certificate: http://docs.mitmproxy.org/en/latest/certinstall.html.

To automatically change parts of the URL, you can use mitmproxy's [`--replace`](http://docs.mitmproxy.org/en/latest/features/replacements.html) option or a custom [inline script](http://docs.mitmproxy.org/en/latest/scripting/inlinescripts.html).